# CURL cuts off URL after 74 characters

Tags: macos, bash, shell, curl, download

I'm writing a script that takes a list of ~300 URLs as input, which have the following format:
`http://long.domain.prefix/folder/subfolder/filename.html`

Of that URL, I'd like to save `filename.html`in `./folder/subfolder/` - if that folder structure doesn't exist, it must be created. This works, the folders are being written to disk, however no files are downloaded.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in `cat list.txt`; do

  # strips the URL prefix and trailing slash
  name=${line#http://long.domain.prefix\/}
  /usr/bin/curl -m 10 -f -o $name --create-dirs $fullname

done;
```

For some reason, the `$name` variable is **cut off after exactly 74 characters**, which obviously results in HTTP error codes. I can't give out the exact URLs, but rest assured they are correct, as long as the full URL is being used.

How can I prevent this odd cutting-off behavior?

Comment: Is there anything "odd" at the 75th character in the URLs (like a space or a semicolon or an ampersand)? (Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and linked pages for why `for line in $(cat list.txt)` is a bad idea.) You should also quote your variables to prevent word-splitting, globbing, etc. on the values (and avoid the problems I suggested earlier.

Comment: There are a couple of "." and "_", but they aren't cut off. It's only always the 74th character that makes a difference. Quoting the variables doesn't change this behavior, neither does using `cat list.txt | do ...`.

Comment: If you add `set -x` to the top of the script and `printf 'line = [%s]\nname = [%s]\n' "$line" "$name"` inside the loop do you see the url being used correctly on the curl command line and does `printf` output what you expect for each variable?

Comment: It does look correct: https://gist.github.com/doque/16b09a815558179fb8cb

Comment: If you add `--trace-ascii` to the `curl` call does the outgoing request have the full URL or is it truncated at that point already? Does using `%q` in the `printf` format string instead of `%s` show any control/etc. characters that are unseen normally?

Comment: That does not look correct, notice where the closing `]` is and the `\r` in the variable expansions? That input file has DOS line-endings. That doesn't explain the 74 characters problem on its own though I don't think but isn't going to help anything. I'd fix that and see what you get.

Comment: No abnormal characters using `%q`. I converted the file using `tr -d "\r" < list.txt` and now the output looks like this: https://gist.github.com/doque/d2fc137ad0c9293ee37b

Comment: That output still has the `\r` in the contents. Also that output would indicate that your parameter expansion isn't stripping the domain from the filename the way you wanted it to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79026/discussion-between-doque-and-etan-reisner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Etan Reisner, the solution was to convert the file to Unix-Style line endings.